# What is the workflow of creating a html project for Material design 3 for web with nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js, web, material-design, material3

I could't make the new material 3 design for web work on a simple html page. I'm not aware of the full workflow and documentation is not very great from google.

I did what the documentation said and followed those steps to install nodejs modules of material3 and built the page.
I was expecting the result from [lit.dev playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=37d28012c5ec6de30809bdf4a6e26cb6)
But I didn't see the front end work on my machine.

My [Github](https://github.com/abhinav937/material-3-portfolio-webpage) project link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.